# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the operator $J$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I am reading a linear algebra book. Assume $V$ is a real vector space. If $J : V \rightarrow V$ is linear such that $J^2 = -\mathit{id}$, it follows that the eigenvalues are positive or negative $i$.

What is $i$ in this case? How did he calculate the eigenvectors? What about the eigenvalues? The matrix of $J$ isn't known. This essentially is what is confusing me.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your matrix is similar, over reals, to the Symplectic matrix, commonly denoted by $J$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few points to note. The operator $J$ cannot have any eigenvector in $V$, because such an eigenvector $v\ne0$, with respect to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, has to satisfy $J(v)=\lambda v$ and therefore
$$
-v=J(J(v))=\lambda^2v
$$
and so $\lambda^2+1=0$ (as $v\ne0$ by assumption). There is no real number $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^2+1=0$, and therefore no eigenvector we can speak of, given that $V$ is a *real* vector space and it makes no sense to do $iv$ (where $i$ is the imaginary unit, of course).

So it seems that your book is making some confusion.

---

However, attached to any real vector space there is a complex vector space $\hat{V}$. One can define it as $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}V$ (tensor product). Basically, the set of $\hat{V}$ is $V\times V$, with addition defined in the obvious way and, for the complex number $a+ib$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
(a+ib)(u,v)=(au-bv,bu+av)
$$
In the case of $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, this is just seeing $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$: if you take $w\in\mathbb{C}^n$, you can write
$$
w=u+iv
$$
where $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and we can identify the pair $(u,v)$ with the vector $u+iv$.

The operator $J$ induces an operator $\hat{J}\colon\hat{V}\to\hat{V}$ in the obvious way, namely $\hat{J}(u,v)=(J(u),J(v))$ and you can check linearity (as complex vector space).

This new operator $\hat{J}$ also satisfies $\hat{J}^2=-\mathit{id}$ and here the eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$ appear, with their eigenvectors.

Comment: That makes so much sense.

Answer (score 2):

That $i$ is the complex number $i$. If $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $J$ and if $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then$$J\bigl(J(v)\bigr)=J(\lambda v)=\lambda J(v)=\lambda^2 v.$$But $J\bigl(J(v)\bigr)=-v$ too. So, $\lambda^2=-1$, and therefore $\lambda=\pm i$.

Comment: Thank you. I have the following questions. How do we know that this is the only eigenvalues ? What is is i in this case? V is a real vector space ?

Comment: The answers are: because that is what I proved; I provided the answer to that question in my answer; yes, because you stated so in your question.

Comment: Since $V$ is a real vector space, what does it mean $iv$, for $v\in V$?

Comment: @egreg What I did proves that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $J$, then $\lambda^2=-1$. So, $J$ has no real eigenvalues. And this proves that if we consider the complexification $V_{\Bbb C}$ of $V$ and if we consider $J$ as an endomorphism of $V_{\Bbb C}$, then its eigenvalues are $\pm i$.

Comment: I disagree; since $V$ is a real vector space, an eigenvalue *must* be real, so it cannot be $\pm i$. There is no real number $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^2=-1$ and here the bucket stops.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that J^2= -1.  That is, given any vector u, applying operator J to it twice gives -u.

v is an eigenvector of J, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, if and only if $Jv= \lambda v$.  Given that, applying J again, $J^2v= J(\lambda v)= \lambda JV= \lambda(\lambda v)= \lambda^2 v$ and, in this case, $J^2v=-1$ for all vectors so we have $\lambda^2= -1$.  Since i is defined as a root of -1, the two eigenvalues are i and -i as those are the only two complex numbers whose square is -1.